# Suggestion list on text box skip values

Tags: jquery

I have added a suggestion list to my text box. With my script I am getting suggestion, But on blur if text is type other than suggested list it removed from my text box and value becomes blank of text box.

```
    <input name="poetname" type="text" id="poetname"  maxlength="80" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" style="display:none;"/>
    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

My `lookup` function

```
function lookup(poetname) { 
    if(poetname.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        //alert("Hiiii");
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+poetname+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My `fill` function

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#poetname').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 500);
}
```

I wish if value entered other than suggestion in my text box than on blur my text box shouldn't be empty or null.

Comment: You have a gracious mix of inline CSS and Javascript.. Events (click, blur, ect) should be handled AND attached via Javascript (non-inline) - same with the CSS..  reading this makes me want to cry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not passed a parameter into fill, it should be onblur="fill(this.value);"